# Refresh select menu after new selected allocation

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have the following select menu, I want that the selected value can be changed after the dropdown list already got loaded.

```
 <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectXX" name="matnr">
           <ion-option selected disabled value="">Choose Matrixnumber...</ion-option>
           <ion-option *ngFor="let matnr of matrixnumbers" [selected]="(matnr == selectMatnr) ? true : false">{{matnr}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

Now we have the case, that the selectMatnr can be changed during the runtime. But when I assign another value to selectMatnr, which is actually equal to matnr, the dropdown list get not be reloaded with the new selected value (selectMatnr). Is it possible to refresh the ion-select programmatically that the ion-option get new loaded?

Comment: Your question is not really clear. What do you mean by "reloaded" ? Can you provide images to explain your problem ?

Comment: Your question remains unclear for me,  as what I understood,  ngModelChange could help you